# Convert Irregular Varchar to Numeric

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, decimal, varchar

I have a table with over 16,000 rows depicting money owed on customer bills. Unfortunately, the amount owed was set up in a strange way - monetary amounts are stored as varchar and for any time when money is due, the minus sign is on the right of the number like this:

```
Amount
36.30
21.48-
132.65-
87.91-
1.20
```

I have added a new column to my table called `Amount_num`, and I would like to do an update to my table that will give me the following:

```
Amount    Amount_num
36.30       36.30
21.48-      -21.48
132.65-     -132.65
87.91-      -87.91
1.20        1.20
```

I tried the following update query:

```
UPDATE [CHARGE_TABLE]
SET [Amount_num] = CAST ([Amount] as decimal (18,2))
```

This gives me 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric'. What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your strange string format.

```
UPDATE [CHARGE_TABLE]
SET [Amount_num] = convert(numeric(18,2), Case when Amount like '%-' then '-' else '' end + REPLACE(Amount, '-', ''))
```

Comment: While this should fix the issue shown here, the OP may still have problems where the data doesn't all match this format as well as the normal numbers. Often when varchar is used when It should not be, then junk gets stored. I say this only so the OP won't reject the answer if it still doesn't work.

Comment: This actually worked! Luckily the data wasn't as messy as it could have been - no words or other symbols that didn't belong. Thank you both for  you help!!